# Issue parsing JSON object with .map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON object returned and I'm trying to parse it to get the value in `identifier`. Here's what the object looks like if I `console.log` it:

```
Object {rows: Array[33], time: 0.015, fields: Object, total_rows: 33}
fields: Object
rows: Array[33]
  0: Object
       cartodb_id: 28
       coordinates: "41.959836,-87.681545"
       created_at: "2015-03-05T14:40:43Z"
       id: "28"
       identifier: "Store Number: 28"
  1: Object
  2: Object
```

Here's how I'm trying to parse it:

```
$.getJSON('https://URLHERE, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var ticks6 = data.rows.map(function() {
                return data.rows.identifier;
            });
```

`ticks6` returns an array with all values as "undefined". I've tried a bunch of different combinations here and can't get it to parse out the right piece.

Comment: `data.rows.identifier` is really undefined, What do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('https://URLHERE', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var ticks6 = data.rows.map(function(ele) {
        return ele.identifier;
    });
    console.log(ticks6);
});
```

Inside the `.map` function, you were accessing `data.rows`, that's the *entire* array.  You want to access `ele` (the 1st parameter passed to the callback), which is each *element* in the array.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! Any guesses why the data is returned in a somewhat random order? Store # 28-33 then 1-11 then 13-27 then 12. They are in order 1-33 in my table

Comment: @jonmrich: How are you making that JSON?  Did you add an `ORDER BY` in your query?

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, MySQL doesn't know how to order your rows.

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes a function which is run against each item in the array. The return value is what is saved in that slot of the array. So you probably meant to write:

```
var ticks6 = data.rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.identifier;
});
```